# How to echo to a remote Raspberry Pi terminal over SSH

Tags: ssh, ethernet

The idea is: if I remotely ssh into my Raspberry Pi, is there a way to echo to the Raspberry Pi's terminal?

Assuming I haven't entered desktop mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console is on /dev/tty0 so

```
echo string >/dev/tty0
```

You might have to add yourself to the tty group

```
sudo adduser pi tty
```

Comment: I did the second line, still permission denied to tty0 :(

Comment: You have to log in again before changes like this are effective.  I'm not familiar with joan's use of `adduser` here, so if that doesn't work, try `sudo usermod -G tty -a pi` (and login again).

Comment: I have ran both add user commands, both work, but permission is still denied to tty0

Comment: Did you close the ssh session and restart?  Are you using Raspbian?  What does ls -l /dev/tty0 report?  What does groups report? tty0 is tty digit zero.

Comment: `ls -l /dev/tty0` reports `crw------- 1 root root 4, 0 May  8 19:05 /dev/tty0`
and 
`groups` reports `pi adm tty dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users netdev input spi gpio`
I beleive this works when I am root user, I just cannot seem to add pi to the list of users (and yes I have reboot each time)

Comment: Try /dev/tty1.  Do you have an old system?  uname -a will show your kernel version.